duck db errors on decimal values in parquet
I'm new to using duck db as a quick way to nose around parquet files on S3, but it's problematic.
I think the issue is with negative decimal values.  It might be something else, but it's only DECIMAL(11, 8) fields that it chokes on, and a clue is that north-west hemisphere latitudes (positive) come back fine but longitudes (negative) do not.  I get this error:
Error: Invalid Input Error: Invalid decimal encoding in Parquet file
If I pull the same fields using Spark SQL, the data comes back fine.  It's only duck db that can't handle it.
So with positive latitudes and negative longitudes...
this fails...
SELECT longitude 
FROM read_parquet('s3://bucket/path/', hive_partitioning = 1);

And this works fine...
SELECT latitude 
FROM read_parquet('s3://bucket/path/', hive_partitioning = 1);

Also, CAST(longitude AS ???)  doesn't work for string, double, or anything else.
Any ideas to get these values into duck db?

I do not know Duck DB.  but maybe you have to declare an extra bit for the sign.
eg. DECIMAL(12, 8)   instead of DECIMAL(11, 8) ???

using spark sql, the data seems perfectly fine and loads without issue, so it seems like duck db thing more than a problem with the underlying data or the encoding of it.
